# Should I move repeating foreign keys into separate table?

Tags: database-design, foreign-key, normalization

**Idea**

Users can upload lots of items and send them from processing. From the upload settings I can set a `channel` to which the uploaded items belong to. Channel is a separate entity. Currently I set the chosen channel`for each uploaded item. Having **Many To One** relationship between`item`and`channel`.

There actually exists `upload_process` table as well. When upload is started, a process is created to capture any metadata and store the state of the running process.

Currently all the queries that deal with `Items`, directly use the `channel_id` from on the item itself, but all the items that are uploaded in one process **always** have the same `channel`.

**Example**

- User uploads 100 items and chooses Channel 1.
- Upload process is created, storing information like process status, who uploaded, upload date...
- When processing, each item channel is set to Channel 1.
- I end up having 100 items with foreign keys pointing to Channel 1

**Question**

Should I move the `channel` relationship to the `upload_process` entity and store that there instead of each individual item?

There are over 10 million `items` in the database. Currently there are max 2 joins on all the queries that deal with items and queries run max 2 seconds, adding another join table shouldn't hurt the performance that much.

What is better here design wise? Thanks!

Comment: Design discussion has been **[moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36334/discussion-on-question-by-vaelyr-should-i-move-repeating-foreign-keys-into-separ).** Please continue there, thank you.